# Enable/disable not working with flexdashboard+shinyjs

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, shinyjs

I am aware of [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/29) and it apparently having being solved, but I've double checked I've got the latest versions of the relevant packages and neither `disable` nor `disabled` seem to be working.

Minimal example:

````
---
title: "test"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard

---

```{r global, include=FALSE}

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(flexdashboard)
```

```{r}
print(sessionInfo())

disabled(checkboxGroupInput("a", label = "heck", choices = 1:3))
disable(id = "a")
```
````

Session info:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] flexdashboard_0.5.1.1 shinyjs_1.0           shiny_1.3.2          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2      digest_0.6.21   later_0.8.0     mime_0.7       
 [5] R6_2.4.0        jsonlite_1.6    xtable_1.8-4    magrittr_1.5   
 [9] evaluate_0.14   stringi_1.4.3   promises_1.0.1  rmarkdown_1.15 
[13] tools_3.6.0     stringr_1.4.0   httpuv_1.5.2    xfun_0.9       
[17] yaml_2.2.0      compiler_3.6.0  htmltools_0.3.6 knitr_1.25
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted and deleted comment saying I needed to use `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` which was pretty much correct, though to be precise, it needs to be `useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)`. If OP sees this, feel free to post as an answer so you can get proper credit.